# How to detect disconnected user in ioredis

Tags: socket.io, ioredis

I am newbie on socket.io and ioredis. This code is running fine. But I still couldn't figure out a way to detect disconnected user (when a user close the tab) and show online users to all clients.

```js
    redis.subscribe("users");
    redis.on("message",function(channel,message){
        console.log('Receive message %s from channel %s', message, channel);
        io.emit(channel,message);
        io.on("disconnect",function(socket){
            console.log("a user disconnected");
        });
    });
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Updated for socket.io-redis

```js
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);
    var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
    io.adapter(redis({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379 }));
    
    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
      var current_user = {};
      socket.on('message', function(data) {
        current_user = json.Parse(data);
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', data);
      });
    
      socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log(current_user); // Now I know which user is disconnected ? 
        io.emit("dc_user",current_user);
      });
    });
```

is this a good approach to inform other clients that which user is disconnected ?

Comment: You are listening to redis events but emitting with socket.io? I would suggest using socket.io-redis adapter, https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis

Comment: Documentation is not good in socket.io-redis. I couldn't understand how to get published event from back-end ? I use redis to publish from backend.

Comment: see my answer, if you have any questions - feel free :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the socket.io-redis adapter:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379 }));

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

  socket.on('message', function(data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', data);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    io.emit('user disconnected');
  });


});
```

Comment: How to know which user is disconnected ? should we create new current_user variable for each connection ? I update my question according to your answer. Please check it out. Also How can I subscribe a published event from server. For example users event and message events are different events from back-end... I use redis.subscribe("users") for it with ioredis.